# Do I need core data migration here?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I am playing around with core data, and may make changes by adding/deleting entities after values have been added - do I need core data migration for this, or will deleting and reinstalling the app on my device be sufficient?

Comment: You need to use lightweight migration in core data. Reinstalling is not a solution.

Comment: Yes, Reinstalling is a temporary fix. Better to use core data migration, please check the following link.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/174025/lightweight-migrations-in-core-data-tutorial